# QT, socket.io and boost integration undefined references errors

Tags: c++, qt, boost, socket.io

I'm new to Boost and fairly starter with QT, so I'm unaware about how the packaging system works in QT, Boost and CPP as well.

I'm trying to integrate `Socket.IO` using `Boost` in QT following [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#without-cmake) tutorial. I'm trying to do it without CMake because it looked more understandable to me. 
The errors and warnings I'm receiving are in this picture:
[image: Errors]

All that I've done so far is this:
-Downloaded and unpacked Boost
-Commands history:

```
254  ./bootstrap.sh
255  ./b2 --help
256  ./b2
257  ./bjam install --prefix="./" --with-system --with-date_time --with-random link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi
258  git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp.git
```

-Copied the content of `src` folder in the github repo to my project under the folder name `siosrc`
-Updated the `pro` file and this is its content:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
            siosrc/sio_client.cpp \
            siosrc/sio_socket.cpp \
            siosrc/internal/sio_client_impl.cpp \
            siosrc/internal/sio_packet.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

INCLUDEPATH += /home/akash/Softwares/Boost/boost_1_61_0/include/ \
                /home/akash/QTProjects/SioCpp/socket.io-client-cpp/lib/websocketpp/ \
                /home/akash/QTProjects/SioCpp/socket.io-client-cpp/lib/rapidjson/include/ \
                /home/akash/Softwares/Boost/boost_1_61_0/lib/
```

All the steps I've performed is what I could figure out from the github readme and [socket.io's cpp blog](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/), which seems outdated to me since the location of source file `sio_packet.cpp` isn't correct with respect to the file's location in the github repo.

I hope I've been descriptive enough and someone can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is not linking to `boost::system`.

Assuming that you've built `boost` for `linux` according to the instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)  (i.e. into the directory at the `$BOOST_ROOT` environment variable) you can add the `boost` library directory to the `pro` file, followed by the `boost_system` lib file:

```
# Ensure that the BOOST_ROOT environment variable has been set
BOOST_ROOT = $$(BOOST_ROOT)
isEmpty(BOOST_ROOT) {
  error("Please set BOOST_ROOT to the location of the Boost libraries")
} else {
  message(Using Boost from: $$BOOST_ROOT)
}

LIBS += -L$${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
LIBS += -lboost_system
```

Note: there are packaged `boost` libraries for `linux` that are installed at `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc and so don't require their path to be defined.

I use a number of `boost` libraries  and find it easier to list the required libraries and use a loop in the `pro` file to add the link dependencies, e.g.:

```
BOOST_LIBS = system log_setup log program_options thread

LIBS += -L$${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
BOOST_LIB_PREFIX = boost_
for(lib, BOOST_LIBS) {
  message(link: $${BOOST_LIB_PREFIX}$${lib})
  LIBS += -l$${BOOST_LIB_PREFIX}$${lib}}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your answer.